# How to perform lookup in form view - OpenERP 7

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I need to control visibility of the field based on the value of another field. That another field is a reference. I think I need to do a lookup pretty much the same way as I can do in a module with `browse` or `search` methods. But how to do in a view?

View:

```
<field name="org_no" attrs="{'invisible':[('country_id','!=','Sweden')]}"/>
```

Model (standard res.partner):

```
country_id: fields.many2one('res.country', 'Country')
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the hard coding, you pretty much have it. Just ensure that the `country_id` field is on the form so it can be used in the attrs on `org_no`.  If you don't want the user to see the country, just put it on as an invisible field.

Comment: In v7, country_id is an external reference from res.country model. So in form I can only see internal reference - some numerical ID associated with a country (and which obviously can be different from installation to installation). Anyway, I found a way to do it with help of `fields_view_get`, also described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208799/openerp-compare-fields-using-external-id

Answer (score 0):

`field_view_get` is static solution problem where once you set the value on domain, view will follow that, so if that's your requirement you can use it.

or else you can use below solution for better and dynamic behavior.

1. Take one `Boolean` field on your object where you wanna control visibility and add it in field as invisible.
2. Write `on_change` method of your field based on what you wanna control visibility and using the on change method you can set the value of the above boolean field.
3. using the First step `boolean` field on `attrs` to make field visible on demand.

Thank You

Comment: Not sure what you refer as static here, but calling up mysterious (because cannot find any documentation or decent example) `setup_modifiers` from `field_view_get` as in example I mentioned before - makes it pretty dynamic (i.e. follows the change on field and updates whole form dynamically).

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use this:

```
<field name="org_no" attrs="{'invisible':[('country_id.name','!=','Sweden')]}"/>
```

because country_id just stores the ID of the country that is selected in your many2one field

Comment: That was the first thing I tried - and got `Unknown field country_id.name in domain [["country_id.name","!=","Sweden"]]`